# How to delay changing background color of a square in a grid if that square's color has just been changed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing an exercise with vanilla javascript that changes a random square in a grid to a random color every 400ms, but the square cannot change color for at least another 3s once once it has changed color. This delay logic is what I'm hung up on.

What's the best way to check to see if the current square has just changed color, and to prevent that square from changing colors for 3 seconds?

As you can see, I've experimented with adding a new class once a square's color has been changed. I've also tried placing the set timeout within the colorChange function.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jdagley77/pen/pwOGpN%20/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class = "box" id="square1"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square2"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square3"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square4"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square5"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square6"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square7"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square8"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square9"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square10"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square11"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square12"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square13"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square14"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square15"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square16"></div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
setInterval(colorChange, 400);

if (square.className = "colored") {
    square.setTimeout(setColor(), 3000);
} 

function colorChange() {
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "purple"];
    var specificColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    var randomId = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 17);
    var square = document.getElementById("square"+randomId);
    square.style.backgroundColor = specificColor;
    square.addClass = "colored";
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

In the solution I have made an array containing eligible squares for color change. Every time we change color that square is removed from the array and a timeout is added which adds the square back into the array after 3s. See if the solution works for you.

```js
var squares = [];
for(var i=0;i<=16;i++)
  squares[i] = i;
var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "purple"];
setInterval(colorChange, 400);


function colorChange() {    
var specificColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
var randomId = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (squares.length-1));
var sq = squares[randomId];
var square = document.getElementById("square"+sq);
square.style.backgroundColor = specificColor;
square.addClass = "colored";
squares.splice(randomId,1);
setTimeout(function(){squares.push(sq);}, 3000);
}
```

```css
#content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class = "box" id="square1"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square2"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square3"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square4"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square5"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square6"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square7"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square8"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square9"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square10"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square11"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square12"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square13"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square14"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square15"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square16"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Clever solution !

Comment: interesting - never thought to use an array to represent each square and then use the randomId variable to access, and then to remove then add the square after the setTimeout. thanks, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a `Square` object that will retain a reference to the dom node, and a flag to see if it was changed in the past 3 seconds?
You can create an array of `Squares`, choose a `Square` and check if it is flagged ; if it isn't, change its color, otherwise, call the `Square` choosing function again.

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/KqGgNb)

Oh, and use `Math.floor` otherwise you won't change the first square.

**JS**

```
const COLOR_CHANGE_INTERVAL = 400;
const DRYING_INTERVAL = 3000;

let Square = function(tag){
  this.dom = tag;
  this.flagged = false;
}

// Create an array and populate it
let squares = [];

// convert from html collection into array
const _squares = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("box"));
_squares.forEach(function(square,idx){
  squares.push(new Square(square));
});

setInterval(chooseSquare, COLOR_CHANGE_INTERVAL, squares);

function chooseSquare(arr){
  var randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  const currentSquare = arr[randomId];
  if(!currentSquare.flagged){
    colorChange(currentSquare);
  } else {
    chooseSquare(currentSquare);
  }
}

function colorChange(square) {
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "purple"];
    var specificColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    square.dom.style.backgroundColor = specificColor;
    square.flagged = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      square.flagged = false;
    }, DRYING_INTERVAL); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works out for you:

```js
setInterval(colorChange, 400);

var timeout = new Array(16);

function colorChange() {
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "purple"];
    var specificColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    var randomId = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 16);
    if(new Date().getTime() - (timeout[randomId-1] || 0) >= 3000) {
      timeout[randomId-1] = new Date().getTime();
      var square = document.getElementById("square"+randomId);
      square.style.backgroundColor = specificColor;
      square.addClass = "colored";
    }
}
```

```css
#content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class = "box" id="square1"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square2"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square3"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square4"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square5"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square6"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square7"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square8"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square9"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square10"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square11"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square12"></div> <br>
  <div class = "box" id="square13"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square14"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square15"></div>
  <div class = "box" id="square16"></div> 
</div>
```